# Parse multilevel JSON to Excel in python

Tags: python, json, excel

I'm trying to parse multilevel JSON to Excel using xlwt.
JSON format is like this:

```
{
     "A": {
              "A1": 0, "A2": 0
          },
     "B": {
              "B1": 0, "B2": 0
          }
}
```

etc.

I've tried following (obviously after opening and loading JSON into Python dictionary):

```
for k in data:
    for l in data.keys():
        for j in l.keys():
            o = []
            o = j
            ws.write(0, l.keys().index(j)+1, l[j])
        ws.write(data.keys().index(k)+1, l.keys().index(o)+1, o)
    ws.write(data.keys().index(k)+1, 0, k[l])
```

But I receive "unicode" object doesn't have attribute "keys"

Comment: Please edit your question and add more information. Which line produces the error? Also, how are you creating the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the package [StyleFrame](https://github.com/DeepSpace2/StyleFrame).

First convert the data to format that can be used in StyleFrame object and then just use the StyleFrame object.

```
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame

data = {'A': {'A1': 0, 'A2': 0}, 'B': {'B1': 0, 'B2': 0}}
formated_data = {col: [data[col][row] for row in sorted(data[col])] for col in data}

StyleFrame(data).to_excel('output.xlsx',
                          row_to_add_filters=0,
                          columns_and_rows_to_freeze='A2').save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did a little testing. See the test case below to highlight how to loop your multilevel dictionary. I can't tell exactly the logic of what you are writing, so I will give a generalized answer:

```
In [44]: data
Out[44]: {'A': {'A1': 0, 'A2': 0}, 'B': {'B1': 0, 'B2': 0}}

In [45]: for i in data:
    ...:     print(data[i])
    ...:     
{'A1': 0, 'A2': 0}
{'B1': 0, 'B2': 0}

#You can see that `i` represents  the key, so you access the value paired with that key by doing `data[i]`. In this case, that value is another dictionary.

In [46]: for i in data:
    ...:     for j in data[i]:
    ...:         print(data[i][j])
    ...:         
0
0
0
0

#This is far less illustrative than my contrived example, but `j` represents the key in the dictionary `data[i]`. So this second loop goes through and prints each value of the nested dictionaries.
```

Let me know if this isn't clear.

Comment: I didn't become a programmer yesterday, yet I have no idea how this code is supposed to answer the question. Maybe I'm just too stupid, but some explanation of what's going on here would be helpful.

Comment: It shows generally how to loop through a multilevel dictionary, which appears to be what the question is asking. The structure of the sample dict is exactly the same structure as OP. I can change it to be the exact same if that is more clear. I'll try to clarify a bit in the answer.

Comment: Well, that's one of the most basic things in Python. He's trying to put it in a spread sheet, but he didn't specify how exactly he is planning to do that...